# Rails 4 + datatables: Datatable not loading properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a table in my `html.erb` view that uses bootstrap nav-tabs, and is filled through partials and embedded Ruby, and for some reason, Datatables will not load the table correctly.

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  console.log("foo");

  $("#datatable-weighin").DataTable();

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log("bar");
  });
});
```

This outputs both `foo` and `bar` when it should, signifying that everything is loading properly, but my table still looks no different than before calling `$("#datatable-weighin").DataTable();`.

Could the fact that I'm using partials and loading variables from the controller, have anything to do with it?  I see that `nav-tabs` has some issued with datatables because the table is hidden, but that should only effect column size, etc. and not just general loading.

Comment: Are you using the datatable-rails gem or did you install manually?  Make sure you've included the datatables js and css files correctly.

Comment: Could it be connected to turbolinks?

Comment: Can you show your HTML table, as well?

Comment: Depends on how and where you load the script. Maybe try `$(document).on('page: load', function() {` instead.

Comment: @Rudzainy I've done that with no luck

Comment: @bkunzi01 it works in the exact same table when its not under `nav-tabs`

Comment: @MichaelGaskill it can't be due to the table, because when I take the table out of the `nav-tabs` divs, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

After looking more carefully at my code I realized that when I was querying for the table using `$("#datatable-weighin")` I wasn't actually returning the table despite the `id` being part of the table:

`<table class="profile-table-table" id="weigh-in datatable-weighin"></table>`

I then changed this to `<table class="profile-table-table special" id="weigh-in"></table>`

...and when I queried for `$("table.special")` it returned the table and datatables started working